# Extract specific data from a text in google spread sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to extract some specific data from a text in Google Spreadsheet but I am having a problem getting exactly the data I want.

The text I am trying to extract is as follow:

`"<strong>Title -</strong> Round and Round
  <strong><br><br>Artist -</strong> Laurie Lipton
  <strong><br><br>Type -</strong> Print
  <strong><br><br>Size -</strong> 18,3 x 23,5 in (46,5 x 59,7 cm)
  <strong><br><br>Medium - </strong> Lithograph
  <strong><br><br>Year -</strong> 2014
  <strong><br><br>Condition -</strong> Excellent`

I can use the formula that @soup gave me, but even in this case it doesn't extract the numbers fully when there are digits. If I have 13.5 x 14.35, I have a cell that displays 13 and the other one 5.

The formula is as follow:

`=arrayformula(value(regexextract(A68, "([\d.]+)\D*([\d.]+)")))`

Comment: Is this text already in the sheet btw or are you using importxml/importdata to pull it in?

Comment: The text is already in the sheet.

Comment: Did the answer below fully solve your particular issue or are you still seeking an answer?

Comment: Sorry for answering now, it does to some extent, I would actually like to know if I could both include comma and dot inside the string so that I do not have to change it when I extract the data? The problem otherwise is that if a number is 14.3 and one row under it is written 13,5 I would have to change the string so that I can extract the data.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets, [`regexextract`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) does the job nicely:

```
=regexextract(Q2, "([\d.]+)\D*([\d.]+)")
```

returns "40" and "30" in two separate cells.

However these are returned as strings, so you'll probably want to convert them to numbers with `value`:

```
=arrayformula(value(regexextract(Q2, "([\d.]+)\D*([\d.]+)")))
```

#### Explanation

The string "([\d.]+)\D*([\d.]+)" is a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) that means: find a group of consecutive digits `\d`, possibly with decimal dots, and capture it (indicated by parentheses); then scroll by any number of non-digits `\D*`, then find another group of digits and capture it too. A tutorial on regular expressions is linked above; the technical description of the features that Google Sheets supports is [here](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt).

Comment: Added explanation to the answer.

Comment: It works well here but I have a problem with another string that includes digits with each number, it doesn't include those but put them in the next cell. Would you know how to solve that? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Okay, I changed the regex so that it allows for decimal dots within a number. So, 40.6 will be in one cell and 30.25 in another.

Comment: I changed the text to show you where I am having a problem, all the strings are actually together in the text that I have so don't take into consideration if there are line after line. Thanks again.

Comment: So it uses decimal comma instead of decimal dot. Fine, replace both dots with commas in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve for both comma and decimal if there is one - if not it still treats it the same:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(\d+.?\d*)\D*(\d+.?\d*)")
```

[image]

Update to include the fraction:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(\d+.?\d*|\d+.?\d/\d)\D*(\d+.?\d*|\d+.?\d/\d)\D*(\d+.?\d*|\d+.?\d/\d\s?)?in")
```

Comment: Thanks Aurelie, I would like to know though if I had an extra  (\d*.?\d*), would it work for a double cell only? It doesn't work for me. As well as I have changed the formula to =REGEXEXTRACT(A60,"(\d+.?\d+.?\d*)\D*(\d+.?\d+.?\d*)\D*(\d+.?\d+.?\d*)") because I needed to extract a "/" sometimes, and applying this to a regular two cell didn't work.

Comment: can you share a sample of the other case with the /

Comment: <br><br><strong>Origin -</strong>England<br><br><strong>Dimensions -</strong>34 x 36 1/2 x 22 in. (86.4 x 68.6 x 57.1 cm)<br><br><strong>Type -</strong>Second half 17th century

Comment: Hi Aurelie, did you by any chance found something? Thanks

Comment: @MarcBiessy Yeah sorry work has been busy - I updated the formula to add the variation to the bottom - it should handle all cases now, whether there are 2 or 3 dimensions and all punctuation